# Display lateral view same like google map in my application

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I am developing one navigation based application in which i used google map and google direction api for route navigation but i stuck at one point, i need to show same google map lateral view which is open when we start the navigation.

I have R&D lots off on it but not able to do exactly same like google map lateral view.

I try with following

```
 GMSCameraPosition *camera =[GMSCameraPosition cameraWithTarget:marker.position zoom:50.0 bearing:120 viewingAngle:90];
[[self getMapView] animateToCameraPosition:camera];
```

not succeed to display same.

I need to show same google map as following when i start navigation.Can anybody help me in this point.Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: The Google Maps API does not provide real-time navigation. The only way to do a turn by turn navigation is when to launch the Google Maps app, which means you can not include the turn by tune in your app. However, you might able to take advantage of the iOS 9 split-screen function, and the fact that Google Maps post notification on to the notification center (when it is in background?)

Comment: @kaho i didnot want real time navigation but i just want this type of lateral view

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve using proper bearing between 2 location. (present  and target location)

```
func degreesToRadians(degrees: Double) -> Double { return degrees * .pi / 180.0 }
    func radiansToDegrees(radians: Double) -> Double { return radians * 180.0 / .pi }

    func getBearingBetweenTwoPoints1(point1 : CLLocation, point2 : CLLocation) -> Double {

        let lat1 = degreesToRadians(degrees: point1.coordinate.latitude)
        let lon1 = degreesToRadians(degrees: point1.coordinate.longitude)

        let lat2 = degreesToRadians(degrees: point2.coordinate.latitude)
        let lon2 = degreesToRadians(degrees: point2.coordinate.longitude)

        let dLon = lon2 - lon1

        let y = sin(dLon) * cos(lat2)
        let x = cos(lat1) * sin(lat2) - sin(lat1) * cos(lat2) * cos(dLon)
        let radiansBearing = atan2(y, x)

        return radiansToDegrees(radians: radiansBearing)
    }



let bearingPoint = self.getBearingBetweenTwoPoints1(point1: location!, point2: self.featureLocation)
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: (location?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude: (location?.coordinate.longitude)!, zoom: 50, bearing: bearingPoint, viewingAngle: 45)

self.mapView?.animate(to: camera)
```